# Making A UIWebView Acessible

Tags: ios, uiwebview, accessibility, voiceover

Does anyone have any hints as to making information in a UIWebView accessible?

I've found that using ALT tags on images and links will allow VoiceOver to use the info but is there anything else that I could be doing to improve the user experience for users with visual impairments?

Comment: Before I can answer your question, I need to know more about the kind of content inside this Web view.  Is it simple static content and links, or is there more to it, e.g. forms, Ajax, custom controls?

Comment: Standard HTML elements really - so static text, images, links, forms etc. With controls I would, for example, update a "play" button to "pause" with .js along with any corresponding tag info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I have no suggestions for specific improvements.  My only advice is this:  If you want to make your application accessible to blind users, there is no substitute for testing with VoiceOver with your eyes closed.

Comment: Then there is an option called "screen curtain" as well :)